# How to wait for the end of the element transform property?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this example, after the button is clicked, I first want to transform the box and then show an alert. But here, it first show the alert and then do the transform

```js
const clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');
const box = document.getElementById('box');

clickme.addEventListener("click", () => {
        box.style.transform = `rotate(90deg)`;
    const value = parseFloat(box.style.transform.split('rotate(')[1]);
    if(value >= 90) {
        alert('Hello Rotate')
    }
})
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  transition: .200s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  
</div>

<button id="clickme">
  rotate
</button>
```

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API or timeout

Comment: You can setvan event listener for the transitionend event and at that point test and do the alert if required.

Answer (score 0):

That's the limit for transform for you.
To achieve best performance, a reliable result and actually use the right tools for the right purpose i'd suggest learning CSS animations with keyframes.
It's not that hard and it will allow you to unload some of the tasks from the main thread to the gpu(better SEO and performance).
Else there are plenty of libraries that you could use:

For example: https://animejs.com/

Comment: Why couldn’t they use a transitionend event listener?

Comment: you can use, but that event listener would consume your cpu instead of gpu. That answer was already presented as a comment.

Comment: The point I wanted to highlight is sometimes people overengineer something that could be solved easily with css or even html. And that solution not only requires wierd code, but also a performance loss. JS is not a golden key, we should learn both HTML and CSS along the way.

Comment: Ah, yes I fully take the point about using CSS if possible, I just didn’t think the ‘limit for transform’ had quite explored transform completely.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, the problem is not of the `transform` property or not having keyframes as [Filas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891740/18620006) pointed out, but instead the problem lies in the nature of Javascript.

```
const clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');
const box = document.getElementById('box');

clickme.addEventListener("click", () => {
        box.style.transform = `rotate(90deg)`;
    const value = parseFloat(box.style.transform.split('rotate(')[1]);
    if(value >= 90) {
        alert('Hello Rotate')
    }
})
```

The browser pauses the rendering of the HTML, which is responsible for `box.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';`, and instead prioritizes showing the `alert()`. Here's a [thread](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-i-can-see-the-result-of-documentwrite-only-after-all-the-prompts-and-alert-messages-disappear) that talks about it more.

I assume that in your actual code, you would be using some other function, instead of the `alert()`. In that case, your code should run as you intended, with the transform occurring first, followed by the subsequent commands.

```js
const clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');
const box = document.getElementById('box');

clickme.addEventListener("click", () => {
        box.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)';
    const value = parseFloat(box.style.transform.split('rotate(')[1]);
    if(value >= 90) {
        box.style.backgroundColor="green";  //code that isn't an alert()
    }
})
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  transition: .200s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  
</div>

<button id="clickme">
  rotate
</button>
```

Combine this with a [`transitionend`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_transitionend.asp) event, or a [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function, if you want to sequence the changes in a way that the individual changes/steps are clearly visible to the user.